# Impossible to parse dates as datetime64[ns]

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to parse dates from a CSV file. I have tried doing it when opening csv with pd.read_csv:

```
df = pd.read_csv('Data/file.csv', parse_dates=['Date'], index_col='Date', dayfirst=True)
```

Unfortunately, when doing *type(df.index)*, the function says the index of df is a "pandas.core.indexes.base.Index"... not a "datetime64[ns]"

I have also tried this:

```
pd.to_datetime(df.index, errors='ignore')
```

But again, *type(df.index)* reveals again a "pandas.core.indexes.base.Index".

How can I do it?

Comment: You need to assign the index `df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, errors='coerce')` and you want to `coerce` the errors because with 'ignore' any errors return the same input object (no idea why this is ever desired....) as per the docs. Similarly, errors on reading the csv prevent the creation of a DatetimeIndex, so there the docs also suggest you typecast separately after importing.

Comment: Without sample of your index, we can't help you...

Answer (score 0):

As @ALollz pointed out, that did the trick completely. That is, doing this:

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, errors='coerce')
```